# Como fazer uma componente com variáveis de diferentes tipos?

Tags: portugol

`algoritmo "Analisador Numérico Procedimento"
// Função : Analisar Números com procedimentos LOL
// Autor : Rodrigo Matos Aguiar
// Data : 17/10/2016
// Seção de Declarações 
var
   Cont, NA, S, ND5, NN, SP: Inteiro // Cont - Contador, NA - Número Atual, S - Soma
   // ND5 - Números Divisíveis por 5, NN - Números Nulos, SP - Soma dos Pares
   MD: Real // MD - Média
   Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro) e (B: Real)
   Inicio
   EscrevaL("Soma dos Números: ", A)
   EscrevaL("Média entre os Números: ", B)
   EscrevaL("Total de Números Divisíveis por 5: ", C)
   EscrevaL("Total de Números Nulos: ", D)
   EscrevaL("Soma dos Números Pares: ", F)
   FimProcedimento
inicio
// Seção de Comandos
   para Cont <- 1 ate 5 faca
        EscrevaL("Informe um número: ")
        Leia(NA)
        S <- S + NA
        MD <- MD + NA / 5
        Se (NA % 5 = 0) entao
           ND5 <- ND5 + 1
        FimSe
        Se (NA = 0) entao
           NN <- NN + 1
        FimSe
        Se (NA % 2 = 0) entao
           SP <- SP + NA
        FimSe
   FimPara
   Resultado(S, ND5, NN, SP) e (MD)
fimalgoritmo`

No procedimento, quero colocar variáveis do tipo inteiro e do real, como eu faço isso? Já tentei:

`Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro) e (B: Real)
Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro) + (B: Real)
Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro B: Real)
Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro)(B: Real)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Procedimento Resultado (A, C, D, F: Inteiro; B: Real)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!